# Java server and PostgreSQL connection

Tags: java, postgresql, connection

I would like to make a server (A) in Java. Some clients (B) connect to A and send informations. When (A) receives data from (B) it must store those information into a PostgreSQL server (C).

I want to know how can I manage the connection between (A) and (C). I have two ideas:

1) Create an initial connection from (A) to (B). This connection remains always active.
2) Create a connection between (A) and (B) every time (A) receive a connection from (B), then close the connection (open/close a connection to the db from every client connect to the server)

My worry is about the database timeout.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Use a [JDBC connection pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835090/jdbc-connection-pooling). It will reuse connections when it can, and create new connections as needed.

Then get a connection from the connection pool every time you need to do anything.

Answer (score 3):

Use a JDBC connection pool. Better yet, break out your JEE/Spring hat and don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: These days, it's just JEE or Java EE. It hasn't been called J2EE since 2004. The name was changed with the release of Java 5.

Answer (score 0):

You really should take a look at the hibernate framwork. Not that difficult to implement in your webapplication and its just a solid way to do it.

1. Create db
2. Add hibernate to your project (project properties/frameworks)
3. Create classes for the objects you want to save (take a look at "annotations"
4. Create a sessionmanager or just google for it.
5. Make a DAO (data access object) for eacht class

You can now add al the methods you want to DAO for saving and getting data from database

Then open a session in your controller and let the DAOs do all the work for you