# concurrent request to jersey rest service

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jdbc, jersey

I am developing a very simple REST web service with Eclipse, Tomcat7 and Jersey implementation, with a connection to MySQL. 
Looking to the jersey documentation i know that every request create a new object of the root resource class. But i dont know if every request is independet, for example if one request have to wait a long time, the server will accept more request normaly?

The problem is :
I have 2 main classes, 1 class implements Jersey with annotations(Proxy.java), and other class that connects to a BD(Notificator.java), there is only one instance of this class (Singleton) in order to use only 1 Connection object. The classes who implements Jersey use this class. So, if one of the request is blocked , i dont know if the others will run because they are using the same (Notificator.java) instance.

The relation is N instances of(Proxy.java) uses the only one (Notificator.java) witch have one Connection to a MySQL.

Comment: why do you want to have just one connection to the DB?

Comment: i did it for simplicity, and to avoid concurrence problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jersey is developed on top of servlets. There is a new thread for each of the incoming request. Your code is creating a bottleneck for all the threads as there is a contention for single available connection object. If you have multiple requests then only one request will be using that connection and others have to wait. If the wait is not too long then there is no problem. But if wait is more than the HTTP REQUEST TIMEOUT then your other requests may end up as TIMED OUT.

I understand that you may be having single connection bottleneck due to some business requriement/ complication. So in all such cases where we cannot process all the requests simulataneously and there can be variety of reasons for it, then we should create our web services as Asynchronous. Asynchronous web services work on the model of SUBMIT REQUEST-> REQUEST ACCEPTED(will be processed asynchronously) and JOB URL returned for polling-> CLIENT POLLS till the JOB IS NOT COMPLETED.

Hope it helps!

Comment: "There is a new thread for each of the incoming request" , this was the important point!! thanks so much. I know there is a bottleneck because I use only one Connection, but usually there will be only 2 or 3 simultanious request, so i think there will not be problems with taht. But i will study the "asynchronous web service" .

Answer (score 0):

Try database connection pooling, more on this here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool

[How to establish a connection pool in JDBC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835090/jdbc-connection-pooling)

Comment: thx, but finally my teacher said me that the connection pooling will be dificult to implement, so i only used the keyword "syncronized" in the Notificator class to avoid concurrence problems. I realized too that every call to jersey run independent, so , if one of this calls blocs , the others will run normally.

Comment: With `synchronized` keyword you block other calls. If that is what you need then Ok.

Comment: i block other calls, but when the resource is available , they wake up ? that is what my teacher explained to me. And this works for me.

Comment: Yes, they wake up when the resource is available.