# Should I close my database connections?

Tags: java, mysql, connection, jtable

I was wondering: Should I close my database connection or leave it open in the following scenario:

My application executes and after every 1-2 seconds it updates a table from the database. This happens until the application is terminated.

Basically what would be more optimal and put less stress on the server, every time this is executed about 500 rows need to be updated with at least 11 fields each (at least 5500 fields combined).

I'm currently using the JDBC driver if it matters at all.

EDIT: Also, would it be more efficient to update certain rows or erase the entire table contents and re-write the updated data (Some rows may be completely different in the updated data).

Answer (score 1):

You should use a connection pool for this. [Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835090/jdbc-connection-pooling) about connection pooling outside an application server.

Answer (score 0):

You have to consider dropped connections here as well as stress on the server. You would be better using a connection pool to manage your connections then you don't have this worry.

Answer (score 0):

Try out [HikariCP](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP) for connection pooling. *Disclaimer: I am one of the authors.*