# Apache Wicket application global settings for database connection

Tags: java, spring, oracle, apache, wicket

I wrote small web application with wicket and sql2o. I have several DAO classes where I create new Sql2o instances with hardcoded username and password:

```
Sql2o database = new Sql2o("jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:test", "test", "test");
```

If I change password I would have to change it everywhere. So my question is where and how to put these settings in wicket so it could be accessed from different classes. Maybe I should use .properties file?

Comment: You should NOT create a database connection for every query, as this is extremely slow. I never worked with Sql2o but normally you would use jdbc pool. there are many different ways to do this

Comment: For Basics on connection pooling read this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835090/jdbc-connection-pooling

Answer (score 0):

You can  use a .properties file, where you need to type:

```
jdbc.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/your_database
jdbc.username=user
jdbc.password=password
```

Answer (score 0):

The URL should be chaged to one of the following depending on you configurations

1. jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:port/service
2. jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:port:SID (SID  - System ID of the Oracle server database instance.)
3. jdbc:oracle:thin:@myhost:1521:databaseInstance (By default, Oracle Database 10g Express Edition creates one database instance called XE.)