# Desktop application and DB connection

Tags: java, sql

Lets say I have desktop application with simple login - here, in this part i have to create `Connection`, prepared statement which compares username and password. I use cardlayout- and for example, on another card (`JPanel`) i have `JTable` and `JButton` which retrieves values from SQL table to my `JTable`.... on third JPanel  i have for example  fields for name and password - using for new employee - he will give his name and password - after button click data will be inserted to DB

Now my Question: How does it work in real application? Shall I  make one static method (e.g. `getDBConnection()`) which will create connection (first for login - after login close connection, then create another connection  when i want to select from DB then close it and again if i want to insert something?) `

or  how to do it in smarter/ proper way?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835090/jdbc-connection-pooling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a properties file specific to your application and write a class to load it.

### `MyDatabaseProperties.properties`

```
database.jdbc.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database
database.jdbc.driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
database.jdbc.username = "USERNAME"
database.jdbc.password = "PASSWORD"
```

### Properties.java:

```
public class Properties {
    private static final String PROPERTIES_FILE = "MyDatabaseProperties.properties";
    private static final Properties PROPERTIES = new Properties();

    static {
        try {
            PROPERTIES.load(new FileInputStream("MyDatabaseProperties.properties"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // THROW YOUR EXCEPTION HERE.
        }
    }
}
```

You will find an excellent material on this subject **[here](http://balusc.blogspot.in/2008/07/dao-tutorial-data-layer.html)**.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a DAO (Data Access Object) to access the table Employee, named DAOEmployee for instance (note that this class will contain methods such as addEmployee, removeEmployee, getEmployees). Then, you can have a class (DataBaseConfiguration), responsible of returning the connection to the database (using a static method, for instance).