# What are the different ways to register JDBC drivers with DriverManager

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

actually i already know some ways to load JDBC Driver with support of DriverManager

1)Class.forName(“oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver”);

2)DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());

I am beginner in Java i need to know more methods by that we can load JDBC

Comment: Since Java 7 you don't need to register JDBC 4 drivers. Apart of that, in real world applications you won't open connections manually but use a database connection pool that will handle this for you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835090/how-to-establish-a-connection-pool-in-jdbc

Comment: yeah you are correct , but for information i just need some more other methods if available ...can you help me ? :)

Comment: Why? You're never going to use them. And what makes you think there are any more? And JDBC 4 is dated 2007. Eight years ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually i just want to more type of JDBC drive already i know TYPE1,TYPE2,TYPE3, and TYPE4 instead of any other JDBC driver is available ?
but some where i found TYPE5 hence they are not Officially Recommended by SUN micro system