# How to use a reenterant lock to resolve a deadlock?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, locking, deadlock

```
synchronised()
{
//line1
//line2
// line: waiting indefinitely for DB connection
//line 3
}
```

How to ensure that other threads get access to these lines and the thread currently deadlocked here, somehow releases the lock?

Comment: Use a connection pool.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon: I already have multiple threads coming at me. Can't do anything about threads.

Comment: [Connection Pools](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2835090/823393).

Comment: What do you mean, "ensure that other threads get access to these lines?"  Any thread that executes line 1 and line 2 is obviously going to execute the line that comes after.  What are these threads?  What are they supposed to do?  What is the synchronized block supposed to protect?