# How can i use limited no of db connections in Java Threads

Tags: java, multithreading, jdbc, concurrency, threadpool

In my application,

I'll have to run >10000 threads at a time. These threads will perform some operations in DB.
I'm using thread pool of size 100.
The no of db connections is 10000, which is affecting the performance.

Is there any way i create few (say 50-100) db connections and share them among all the threads?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Use a connection pool of size 100 (or less) as well?

Comment: Wait a minute... if you have a threadpool of 100 threads, how can you have over 10000 threads at a time?

Comment: You are pooling threads. So why not to pool connection to database too? See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835090/how-to-establish-a-connection-pool-in-jdbc).

Comment: Do you have 10,000 cpu cores?

Comment: It sounds like each thread maintains a database connection.   Can you make your database connection short-lived?  For example, in Hibernate, when you need to access the database, get an EntityManager, do the work, and then close the EntityManager.  Your threads will then share the connections using the configured connection pool.

Comment: @plastique, in apache-DBCP, how to limit the no of connections?. I am using the code as given in that link but it is not working