# tomcat 7 how to keep jdbc connection alive for ever

Tags: java, jdbc, tomcat7, database-connection

I have a war that requires a permanent jdbc connection.

I've tried this (context.xml)

```
maxActive="100" 
maxIdle="3" 
maxWait="1000"  
minIdle="1"
```

But the connection still dies after a while. How can i keep a jdbc connection alive 24/7?

thanks

Comment: keeping IP connections open 24/7 is nigh-impossible, if you want to keep such a connection stable (!) you will need to use database connection pools : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835090/how-to-establish-a-connection-pool-in-jdbc

Comment: which db? and why do you want to that? I mean what useful task you trying to achieve by keeping connection alive?

Comment: @SabirKhan it's one of those apps that are used all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: **you cannot keep it alive forever**

At some point something will fail / break. Be it some network interruption, some maintenance of either your software or the database or something else.

So *"I want **one** connection that I can use whenever I need, so it will never close automatically"* is not likely to happen for you.

Instead by using a connection pool, you can have: *"I want to be able to get a valid and working database connection at any point in time"* is quite easy to get in comparison.

Most good connection pools ([hikariCP](http://brettwooldridge.github.io/HikariCP/), [c3p0](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/), tomcat database pool, ...) support configuration options that guarantee (that is: if the database is up and the network connection works) you can get a valid connection when you need it.