# Java Web Project connection with Jsp and Servlet

Tags: java, database, jsp, servlets

I am new to Java web project and am using Jsp and Servlet in it, in order to connect with the database my each and every jsp file is making a new JDBC connection and connecting through it.

Is there any other way I can have a common place for JDBC connection and through that I can communicate with Database?

Comment: I'd look into database connection pooling if I were you. [Something like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835090/how-to-establish-a-connection-pool-in-jdbc)

Answer (score 4):

For simple non-production projects,

```
public class DatabaseConnection{
    private static Connection conn = new Connection(db conn properties);

    public static Connection getConnection(){
         return conn;
    }
}
```

Wherever you need database connections, use

```
DatabaseConnection.getConnection()
```

If you want things like stale condition check etc etc. go for a connection pool. As it would be faster and better to include a open source connection pool than implementing these features manually.

For production environments, you can use Connection Pools like [c3p0](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/), [hikariCP](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP)