# Should I persist JDBC connection or not?

Tags: java, jdbc

For my integration tests I have build common validation class which has methods like

```
public void countcheck(table1, table 2){ // makes a JDBC connection and run the query to check counts and then closes the connection };

public void nullcheck(Table, ColumnName) {// makes a JDBC connection and the run query to make sure there are no Nulls and then closes the connection );
```

and so on.
I distribute these common validation methods as Jars for integration testers. My dilemma is whether I should open and close connection for each method , I don't want testers to worry about opening and closing connections and just worry about calling validation methods. I am looking for alternative design or this is something good enough. My worry is if there in a test suite there are 10 tests then there would be 10 connections going and closing which perhaps is not a good sign? I want testers to worry about makig and closing connections. Its a Junit based test framework and DB is Oracle.

Comment: Your question is not very clear.  If you worry about creating/releasing connection ,  a connection pool will make that as pretty fast.

Comment: @BhaskarMishra Instead why not use a connection pool to get the connection?

Comment: Thanks, I am slightly new to this, connection pool makes sense, so I shall create a pool as the tester kicks of the tests I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You should not "bake in" the decision on handling DB connections into your code. Instead, you should defer this decision to people deploying your framework.

If *they* decide to reuse connections, they could [configure connection pool](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2835090/335858) for that; if *they* decide to open and close connections every time, they could configure the framework without connection pooling.

Your task is reduced to providing the enabling technology to them.

Answer (score 0):

I typically pass a `DataSource` into such Objects (constructors) and get the connection on each business Method. In standalone mode this might mean it is not using a proper pool, but when you onlyexecute a handfull of statements thats no problm.

In production you can then pass in a real pool. The advantage of keeping a data source around as opposed to a Connection is, that this scenario has better self-healing capabilities and reducesthe number of active connections. (It might be not so important in test scenarios, but whynot have generally useable validators).

```
Validator(DataSource ds) {
    this.ds = ds;
}
validate(String val, ...) {
    try (Connection c = ds.getConnection()) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Most drivers have a native DataSource, but you can also have a genericone which implements getConnection() to `return DriverManager.getConnection(url);`. It is also a small interface easily mockable.

If your tests get bigger, you use a simple pooling datasource like the one from Apache Commons DBCP [`DriverAdapterCPDS`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/api-2.1.1/index.html?org/apache/commons/dbcp2/cpdsadapter/DriverAdapterCPDS.html).