# Java connection pool for Informix

Tags: java, informix

Is there any good example of Informix connection pool using Java?

I'm looking for a high-performance connection pool for Informix.

Comment: There is a JDBC driver for informix you can use it like other jdbc. This can help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835090/how-to-establish-a-connection-pool-in-jdbc

Comment: I already have experience with third party solutions for connection pool. But my intention is to use JDBC driver com.ibm.informix because usually this driver is developer and tested for Informix.

Comment: You will use je JDBC IBM driver with a third party, the third party just manage the pool for you, they does not develop drivers for each databases.

Answer (score 1):

[HikariCP](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP#configuration-knobs-baby) is a high performance database connection pool that's compatible with a number of databasesource's, including informix.