# How to access request from ui to database

Tags: java, mysql, database, design-patterns, web-applications

If **DataBase** only accept 20 requests at the same time, but in UI, We have 100 requests at the same time. How to resolve this in java?

Comment: A [connection pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835090/how-to-establish-a-connection-pool-in-jdbc) (which is a *specialized* [object pool pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern)).

Comment: Thanks Elliott.if any other ways to resolve this problem

Comment: Sure! Make the database accept 100 requests at the same time.

Comment: Thank you Elliott

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be look like this:

`select * from table1 where ... fetch first 100 rows only`

Or

You can use this logic

- **MaxActive:** Maximum number of dB connections in pool. Set to -1 for no
  limit.
- **MaxIdle:** Maximum number of idle dB connections to retain in       pool. Set to    -1  for no limit.
- **MaxWait:** Maximum milliseconds to wait     for a dB connection to
  become    available. Set to -1 to wait indefinitely.

Answer (score 0):

As Elliott suggested you can use connection pool or object pool but you may experience performance issues. Next set of requests have to wait till the completion of first 20 requests.
Alternatively, you can increase the number of db threads from 20 to 100.