# Java Database minimize connection creation

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I am a very beginner to Java and for one of my assignments. I have to do database operations. I have this Java code for inserting data to a database and it works fine.

```
public class JavaDBWork
{

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    try
    {
      // create a mysql database connection
      String myDriver = "org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver";
      String myUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test";
      Class.forName(myDriver);
      Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(myUrl, "root", "");

      // create a sql date object so we can use it in our INSERT statement
      Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
      java.sql.Date startDate = new java.sql.Date(calendar.getTime().getTime());

      // the mysql insert statement
      String query = " insert into users (first_name, last_name, date_created, is_admin, num_points)"
        + " values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

    //Other Code
}
```

My question is every time the code runs, my code has to create a database connection and prepared statement objects and as I understand it is a costly operation.

Is there any way that I can keep a single connection to database and use that to perform my database work?

Comment: google "jdbc connection pooling"

Comment: Thanks for answer. Will look into that :)

Comment: The cost of creation of connection is relative, and it is really not that important to consider for 'toy' projects like student assignments. Totally different subject: loading `org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver` is really 15+ years out of date, the MySQL driver class has been called `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` for years now (the `org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver` is just preserved for backwards compatibility).

Comment: Related (although maybe a little dated): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835090/how-to-establish-a-connection-pool-in-jdbc

Comment: such optimisation in command line one shot program ("main") totally has not sense. If You want different type algorithm, show idea.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Yes I agree it is not important in school assignments but I asked it because my assignment is somewhat considerable web project and this is some test code.Thanks for pointing out the outdated driver as well. :)

Comment: @JacekCz Yes code optimization for this program does not make much sense. My complete assignment is a student management system web application and required to put it in a server like Jboss. When such thing happens, I thought of optimizing my code further.Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: servers JBos, Tomcat and others, have CONNECTION POOL ready to go, and is well documented, almost on first page of documentation.

Comment: Pool on the server is 10 lines of configuration (may be specific on server) and 3 lines of Java code

Comment: When using Tomcat or JBoss, you would use connection pooling https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-usagenotes-jboss.html

Comment: Thanks Jacek Cz and Jaydee. When I am deploying the application to an application server, I will follow your guidelines :)

Comment: There's no need to call `Class.forName(myDriver);` (and therefore no need to have the variable `myDriver`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the design pattern Singleton Connection like this :

1- create a class SingletonConnection.java look like that :

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.EmptyStackException;

public class SingletonConnection   {


    private static Connection connection = null ;
    static 
    {
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection
                    ("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gestion_comptes","root","");
        }catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }

    }
    public static Connection getConnection() throws Exception {
        return connection;
    }


}
```

And in your other class call it like that :

```
 public  class DaoImpl{

        public Connection connection = SingletonConnection.getConnection();

        public DaoImpl() throws Exception 
        {
            if(connection==null)
                throw new Exception("impossible de se connecter à la base de données");
        }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I am quite new to java so have to learn design pattern as well. After some search, it seems this approach solves my problem. Thanks again :)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel If so, can you please let me know your suggestion? I do not need codes,just an overview of how to do it.Even an external source would suffice :)

Comment: @Ran_Macavity I am glad to hear that.thanks this approach is using in java application and web. this is a design pattern

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class JavaDBWork {

    private final String DATBASE = "myDatabasename";
    private final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/" + DATBASE + "?useSSL=false";
    private final String USERNAME = "myUsername";
    private final String PASSWORD = "myPassword";

    private Connection databaseConnection;

    // Main Method to init
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // build an javaDBWork with init connection one time
        JavaDBWork javaDBWork = new JavaDBWork();
        // call methods in javaDBWork you like
        javaDBWork.doSomething();
    }

    public JavaDBWork() {
        // create a mysql database connection at init
        this.databaseConnection = databaseConnection();
    }

    private Connection databaseConnection() {
        Connection connection = null;
        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
        return connection;
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        try {
            // create a sql date object so we can use it in our INSERT statement
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            java.sql.Date startDate = new java.sql.Date(calendar.getTime().getTime());

            // the mysql insert statement       
            String sql = " insert into users (first_name, last_name, date_created, is_admin, num_points)" + " values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;

            preparedStatement = databaseConnection.prepareStatement(sql);
            preparedStatement.setString(1, "Lucky");
            preparedStatement.setString(2, "Luke");
            ...

            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
    }
```

You can do something like this.

Init the database connection one time and hold the connection in a object which you call when you need.

EDIT:
Example when you need connection in another class:

```
public class MyMainClass {

    private JavaDBWork javaDBWork;

    // Main Method to init
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MyMainClass();
    }

    public MyMainClass() {
        // build an javaDBWork with init connection one time
        javaDBWork = new JavaDBWork();
        // call methods in javaDBWork you like
        javaDBWork.doSomething();
    }

}


public class JavaDBWork {

    private final String DATBASE = "myDatabasename";
    private final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/" + DATBASE + "?useSSL=false";
    private final String USERNAME = "myUsername";
    private final String PASSWORD = "myPassword";

    private Connection databaseConnection;

    public JavaDBWork() {
        // create a mysql database connection at init
        this.databaseConnection = databaseConnection();
    }

    private Connection databaseConnection() {
        Connection connection = null;
        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
        return connection;
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        try {
            // create a sql date object so we can use it in our INSERT statement
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            java.sql.Date startDate = new java.sql.Date(calendar.getTime().getTime());

            // the mysql insert statement
            String sql = " insert into users (first_name, last_name, date_created, is_admin, num_points)" + " values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;

            preparedStatement = databaseConnection.prepareStatement(sql);
            preparedStatement.setString(1, "Lucky");
            preparedStatement.setString(2, "Luke");

            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)  It helps if we code within the class. What if we want a connection outside the class? Any ideas on that?

Comment: Just put the main() method into the class you need and use as shown yesterday. Maybe you need a global variable. 
See my edit in the answer. :)

Comment: Thanks for the modified answer as well :)