# Java Database Connection Sharing in Multiple Threads

Tags: java, multithreading, jdbc

I am calling my db connection method inside every single thread (using ExecutorService for fixed thread pooling) but if I am not using syncrhonized on the `getConnection` method then it is giving me error that

> the connection has been closed

I am new to multi-threading so  I read the Oracle document for `DriverManager.getConnection()`  and it says that

> "The DriverManager.getConnection() method returns a new Java
>   Connection object every time you call it. Note that although the
>   method is not creating a new physical connection (only a single
>   implicit connection is used), it is returning a new object."

If I am already passing new `Connection` object in each worker thread then how come connection is getting closed.

Comment: You shouldn't be sharing a single connection with different threads. That is trouble waiting to happen (like other threads closing the connection, calling rollback etc. etc.).

Comment: @M. Deinum i am calling new connection object  in each Task that the threads are going to perform.

Comment: Then your question doesn't make sense (as that points to sharing one). Also **which** `getConnection` method are you using the `DriverManager` or a `DataSource`. Also you state you are passing in the connection, why? If it itakes to long for anything to happen, the connection mightb e automatically closed. The thread should obtain a connection itself.

Comment: Time to read about [connection pooling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835090/how-to-establish-a-connection-pool-in-jdbc).

Comment: @M. Deinum   executor.execute(new Technology(hashmap,userservice,logger))                                                 In this Runnable class technology i  have called getconnection method (DriverManager)      Just want to understand how the connection is getting closed when i have called the connection method inside each task. Just want to understand.

Comment: If you call it in the constructor it might be to soon. As it gets used in the `run` method which could take a while before executing (or actually using the connection) which can lead to a forcefully closed connection. ALso please don't add code/config etc as comments as those are unreadable! Instead edit your question and add the additional information.

Comment: Consider including the code in the question - nobody knows what you are actually doing.