# Java MySQl - Opening and closing the connection too often?

Tags: java, mysql, database, performance, jdbc

so for my little project I have a database which generates items as of now. I would like to implement a shop which retrieves the data aswell and saves the items in an ArrayList.

Currently everytime I spawn an item I connect to my database which worked but seems super unefficient to me. However, I have no clue how to work with a ResultSet without connecting to my database in the same method. Is there a static way to it so I can only open and close my database a single time and not everytime I spawn an item? And especially if I have like 10 shops which need to be initialized.

```
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(simple connection to database);

        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

        ResultSet numberOfItemsInDataBase = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT count(*) FROM items;");
```

If I want to use the ResultSet, I need to go all the way back to my connection for it. Is that a bad approach or is it normal to open/close the connection every single time?

Cheers

Comment: Use only one connection for the entire program (or web page).

Answer (score 0):

The term you need to use is Connection Pooling.

Assuming you don't use an application server (which would manage connection pooling on your behalf) you can check out Java/JDBC implementations such as [C3P0](https://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/) or [Apache Commons DBCP](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/). You can find usage examples for [DBCP](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=commons-dbcp.git;a=tree;f=doc;hb=refs/heads/master) and [C3P0](https://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#using_c3p0)

See also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835090/how-to-establish-a-connection-pool-in-jdbc).