# JDBC Too Many Connections Error

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, resultset

I know this probably is a similar question from the rest, (well originally, before I tried something new, it was a bit unique but it never solved the main problem), but I probably need to discuss this with someone who can help because I could never get what's causing this despite already reading various posts from this site. Bottom line is I need to keep on making plenty of sequential queries but I ended up making too many connections.

What my program does is that it displays data about each member and that it's sort of a tree or network where, in order to get the data you need for each member, you have to scout through every other member that points to that current member (or child's data) , and the data of the member that points to the member that points to the current member (or grandchild's data) and so on. Hence, why I need to keep making queries cause I need to get the data off of each child. Each node has I think a minimum children of 5 and on my 34th member, it gave off that "Too Many Connections" error.

I have read how to open and close the Connections and all but am I still doing it incorrectly? I've tried changing the max connections but that's not really a long term solution for me. Here's how I do it:

```
public class SQLConnect {

private Connection con;
private Statement st;
private ResultSet rs;

public SQLConnect() {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull", "root", "");
        st = con.createStatement();

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error in constructor: " + ex);
    }
}

//this method gets called before I make another query
public void reconnect() {
    try {
        st.close();
        con.close();
        if (con.isClosed()) {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname", "root", "");
            st = con.createStatement();
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SQLConnect.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

//sample method on how I do queries
public ResultSet getMemberViaMemberId(String mID) {
    try {
        String query = "CALL getMemberViaMemberId(" + mID + ");"; //procedure call
        rs = st.executeQuery(query);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + ex);
    }

    return rs;
}

}//end of class
```

The way I call it in my JForm is this..

```
SQLConnect connect;

public Class(){
   connect = new SQLConnect();
}

public void methodThatGetsCalledALot(String current_id){
    connect.reconnect(); //refer to SQLConnectClass displayed above
    ResultSet member = connect.getMemberViaMemberId(current_id);
    try{
        if (member.next()) {
            lastName = member.getString("last_name");
            firstName = member.getString("first_name");
        }

        //display data...
    } catch (SQLException ex){
    }
}
```

The code:

```
connect.reconnect();
ResultSet rs = connect.callSQLMethod();
```

is the most essential bit and is called by every class, and by every method that needs to fetch data. I have to acknowledge that I never bother closing ResultSet because often times it's inside a loop and gets replaced with new data anyway.

Again, my problem is: I cant continue fetching data anymore because of too many connections. Am I really closing things properly or am I missing something? Any suggestions on how to fix this? If my question is too confusing, I'd add more details if required. Thank you. If anyone's to keen on freely helping me out, I'd go for some emailing. Thank you! And Happy New Year btw.

Comment: You are closing connections too often!

Comment: This is not a good design, what happen if some resultset is big and you need another "callSQLMethod"?

Comment: Well, probably my reason is to catch exceptions that say I cannot do anything to resultset since connection has been closed. Hence, why I call that reconnect method.

Comment: How about using some [connection pool](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2826212/need-code-to-create-connection-pool-in-java)?

Comment: @RC. I very much know it isn't a good design but that's cause I'm such a beginner and when I run out of luck in trying to solve things the good way, the bad designs always covers. That's why I came to ask. Anyway, what I do is make sure I get what I need from the past resultset call before I do a new one.

Comment: How will using a pool affect my overall code from it's current structure and the way it's called in the JForm? Will I still need that reconnect method?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/sqldatasources.html

Comment: Thanks for the link. Tho, I don't know how to plus or (if this finally solves my problem) check your answer here.

Comment: _" I run out of luck in trying to solve things the good way, the bad designs always covers"_ -- Actually, NO.  This means you have not understood the "good way" and are implementing it incorrectly.  You would be much better served by studying and correctly implementing the "good way" instead of hacking at it and trying random things until it seems to work, but then breaks in new unexpected ways.

Comment: For the record, I think the pattern you're describing in your data is sometimes called "hierarchical".

Comment: @JimGarrison Thank you for the advice. Tho I resort to the methods of the dark side because of poor comprehension skills especially when it gets deeply technical, but I've been working on that ever since I began learning things myself instead of relying on school.

Comment: @Jake I knew there was a one term word for what I was describing. Thank you for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be creating a lot of connections and recursing with the ResultSet open. Don't create new connections all the time, all you need is one connection and don't reconnect all the time. You actually don't need the reconnect method at all (unless you connection closes automatically, in which case you can check if it is closed before executing query). And you need to close the ResultSet once you are done retrieving values.

All you need is the data and not the resultset.  So take the data and release the resource ie `ResultSet`. So do this -

In your `getMemberViaMemberId` don't return `ResultSet`, in that method itself, iterate through the resultset and create the object for the row and store it into a collection and return that collection **after closing the ResultSet**.  And dont call `reconnect` method at all.

Close the single connection that you have when exiting the program.

Comment: Your answer looks good as it kinda clears my confusion on how I should re-code it and I'll get back to you once I've implemented this. But you did get one thing correct, the connection does close automatically and I get an error that says cannot do stuff cause after connection is closed. That's why I created reconnect because of that error and in addition attached con.close() before I re-create the connection to make sure it is surely closed..